# Limiting the UI language drop-down in the Kentico Pages application

Tags: localization, kentico

I'm building a multilingual site in Kentico where I want a user to have limited access to the languages that they can create in the **Pages** application.  I can specify which languages the user can edit using the **Languages** tab in the user properties as shown in the [User management](https://docs.kentico.com/k10/managing-users/user-management) page in the Kentico documentation.

The result of this is that if my user tries to view a language that they have not been assigned to and has no page created yet is that they receive a permission error/warning:

> You are not allowed to create this culture version.

What I want to do is limit the drop-down list in the **Pages** application so that I can only select languages that I have permission to change.  I can't find any settings that might limit the drop-down to assigned languages only.

Ideally, the user should only be able to see pages that they can edit in the Pages application for my use case as there are in excess of 30 languages.

How can you limit the UI language drop-down to show only languages that the user is allowed to see?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The language drop-down in the pages application is ultimately provided by the `LanguageMenu` control (which you can find in `CMSModules\Content\Controls\LanguageMenu.ascx`).  You need to make a copy of this and modify the `Page_Load` method in order to limit the languages base upon the set cultures (if any).

A very quick example is to add the following code before the loop that builds the list items:

```
var userCultureIDs = new List<Int32>();
var userCulturesSet = false;
if (CurrentUser.Bindings.CollectionNames.Contains("UserCultures") && CurrentUser.Bindings["UserCultures"].Count > 0)
{
    foreach (var userCulture in CurrentUser.Bindings["UserCultures"])
    {
        userCultureIDs.Add((Int32)userCulture["CultureID"]);
        userCulturesSet = true;
    }
}
```

and then inside that loop, make the first line:

```
if (userCulturesSet && !userCultureIDs.Contains(culture.CultureID) && !CurrentUser.CheckPrivilegeLevel(UserPrivilegeLevelEnum.GlobalAdmin)) continue;
```

This ensures that if you're Global Admin, you get everything and that - if no languages are set - you get the default list.

As is usual with best practice, you're better off making duplicates of these controls before you modify them to make sure that you don't cause any unintended side-effects.  Keeping that in mind, be aware of the control chain:

1. CMSModules\Content\CMSDesk\Default.aspx
2. CMSModules\Content\Controls\ContentNavigation.aspx
3. CMSModules\Content\Controls\TreeLanguageMenu.ascx
4. CMSModules\Content\Controls\LanguageMenu.ascx